# How to find expected value of np.array using scipy.stats?

Tags: scipy

I am trying to get the expected value of a NumPy array but I am running into a problem when I pass my array into the function here is an example of what is happening:

```python
a = np.ones(10)
stats.rv_continuous.expect(args=a)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    stats.rv_continuous.expect(args=a)
TypeError: expect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

If I try  `stats.rv_continuous.expect(a)` , I get this error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_argcheck'
```

Can someone tell me how to get `scipy.stats` to work with an array?

update:
following bob's comment I changed the code to:

```html
st=stats.rv_continuous()
ev = st.expect(args=signal_array)
print(ev)
```

where signal_array is a numpy array. However I now get this error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\TickingClock\Main.py", line 35, in <module>
ev = st.expect(args=signal_array)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2738, in expect
vals = integrate.quad(fun, lb, ub, **kwds)[0] / invfac
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 351, in quad
retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 465, in _quad
return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2722, in fun
return x * self.pdf(x, *args, **lockwds)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1866, in pdf
args, loc, scale = self._parse_args(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: _parse_args() got multiple values for argument 'loc'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create an instance of `rv_continuous` ?

Comment: thanks I tried creating an instance, however I still get an error. I updated the post with the information I have

Comment: That's because you cannot use it directly, you should use a derived class (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html).

Comment: Are you sure it is not [mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) what you mean?

Comment: no I dont want just the mean. What i cannot understand from the doc you linked is how to add my array

Comment: First of all could you define the distribution of the random variable whose expected value you want to calculate?

Comment: Please edit the OP  to show the mathematical operation you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.stats.rv_continuous`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) is a class that must be subclassed and instantiated before calling its `expect` method. At a minimum, the subclass needs a `_pdf` or `_cdf` method. It cannot "just work" with an array, because an array does not define a probability distribution.

Your question includes "I am trying to get the expected value of a NumPy array", yet you commented "no I dont want just the mean", but these seem contradictory if "expected value" is even defined for an array. (I'm not aware of a standard definition for the expected value of an *array*, so I am making an assumption about how the definition for the expected value of a *random variable* might be adapted to an array containing independent observations of a random variable.) From Wikipedia "Expected Value", for instance:

> In probability theory, the expected value (also called expectation, expectancy, expectation operator, mathematical expectation, mean, average, or first moment) is a generalization of the weighted average. Informally, the expected value is the arithmetic mean of a large number of independently selected outcomes of a random variable.

If you mean that you want the expected value of some function of a random variable (again assuming that we have generalized the definition to the case of an array), maybe you want
[`scipy.stats.rv_histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_histogram.html), which uses a normalized histogram of data as the distribution's `pdf`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
x = np.ones(10)
hist = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(3))
dist = stats.rv_histogram(hist)
dist.pdf([0, 1, 2])  # array([0., 1., 0.])
```

Its `expect` method does not produce the result I would expect for the edge case example of `x = np.ones(10)`, but it should do something reasonable for  practical data sets, although it might emit warnings.

For instance,

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
x = np.random.rand(10000)
hist = np.histogram(x, bins=50)
dist = stats.rv_histogram(hist)
dist.expect(lambda x: x**2)  # 0.33645365355131046
stats.moment(x, 2, center=0)  # 0.3365266431887173
```

But you are still probably better off just taking the sample mean of the function applied to the array.

```py
np.mean(x**2)  # 0.3365266431887173
```